# compile in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: netbeans-7.1

I couldn't compile project in netbeans 7.1 in Widows 7 ,the error is "mkdir.exe stop working" I find mkdir.exe in MinGW>Msys>1.0>bin and run but didn't solve this problem . when I run a project the output is :

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Program Files/NetBeans 7.1.1/c++2'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/c__2.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Program Files/NetBeans 7.1.1/c++2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
      0 [main] mkdir 4516 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to mkdir.exe.stackdump
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Program Files/NetBeans 7.1.1/c++2'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Program Files/NetBeans 7.1.1/c++2'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o] Error 5
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 7s)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and after installing msys separately and adding c:\msys\1.0\bin directory to the PATH variable, problem was solved. I had to restart NetBeans.