# C++ Netbeans Unable to compile

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans

I  am currently using Netbeans 7.4, MinGw and had been having problems for my first compilation.
It says, mkdir stops responding whenever I try to compile and then the following debug log appears.

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf

make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/NetBeans/Welcome_1'

"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows

/welcome_1.exe

make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/NetBeans/Welcome_1'

mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows

0 [main] mkdir 3296 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to mkdir.exe.stackdump

make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/welcome.o] Error 5

make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/NetBeans/Welcome_1'

make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2

make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/NetBeans/Welcome_1'

make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

Below here is my compiler paths.
[image]

Please help.

Changed make command path to C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe and encounterd the following error.

```
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf

make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/NetBeans/Welcome_2'

"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows

/welcome_2.exe

make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/NetBeans/Welcome_2'

mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows

rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/welcome.o.d"

g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/welcome.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-

Windows/welcome.o welcome.cc

In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\cwchar:44:0,

from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,

from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iosfwd:40,

from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:38,

from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,

from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,

from welcome.cc:31:


c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:37:20: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory

  #include <stddef.h>
                    ^

compilation terminated.

make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/welcome.o] Error 1

make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeans/Welcome_2'

make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2

make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeans/Welcome_2'

make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2



BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 955ms)
```

Comment: "Error 5" means "permission denied": you cannot write to or create "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/welcome.o".

Comment: But I am running as an administrator.

Comment: I think my mkdir crashed thats why the folder is not created and therefore permission is not granted to create.

Comment: You may have the same issue reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850381/compile-in-netbeans-7-1. In that case it reported "Error 2", not the "Error 5" that you are seeing. It may be worth a try anyway.

Comment: I got some other bug logs...see next post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it fixed by installing more MinGw packages. Must have missed some packs while downloading. I also tried rekeying my Path in environment variables.Thanks alot for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same errors and used the basic setup installation for mingw.  What additional packages need to be installed since mingw has a long list of packages.

Comment: Did you try setting windows path environment variables?

Comment: You might want to re-download your minGW packages again, there might be some errors and missing packages. If you can, try a different mirror to download.